# Toggle show not working

Tags: jquery

I am struggling with this piece of code. What is inside the div tag with console-debug as an id doesn't stand out.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#console-debug").hide();// By default hide the console-debug
        $("#btn-debug").click(function() { 
            $("#console-debug").toggle();//Then toggle back to show console-debug
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Where the console debug, did you debug?

Comment: Whats your html? Your example works http://jsfiddle.net/eqrprwpa/

Comment: There is no problem in the code. I have checked it. http://jsfiddle.net/4kLomwtc/

Answer (score 1):

There isn't enough info to debug your problem. You should put more effort into finding the root cause.

Use developer tools to debug the problem - and try to narrow down the problem.

1. try running the `$('#console-debug').toggle()` from the console, does it work?
2. if the toggle works then the problem is with the click handler, add `console.log` or place a breakpoint in the `click` handler - is it being called when you click?
3. if the toggle doesn't work, use the inspector to look at your #console-debug div style attributes and css, maybe the toggle works but it has other reason for not being visible.

Comment: I tried to inspect the source code on google chrome, and I found this message:    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)     http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js.       So could anyone give me a good url for Jquery UI 1.11.3. May be the problem comes from there.